Mesh clipping issue once model is posed
Blender user of about a week here.
File for reference: 
I have a project which I've downloaded for a bit of fun and have messed around rigging it correctly and posing it.
Now that I want to 3d print the model, I've run into issues with the posed final product.
Some parts of the wings are turning themselves inside out and clipping through other parts of the wings and I'm at a loss as to how to fix it so that the wing "membrane" is consistent and doesn't clip/invert.
The model when at rest has good thickness for 3d printing, but when posed with the wings folded is where all the issues are.
Rest position: 
And Posed position:
Pose position with "inside" faces highlighted

Somethings wrong with the way it is rigged. Are you posing it with sculpt tools? or shapekeys? Or is it actually rigged with an armature and whatnot?

I am posing with an armature

I would start by checking the weight painting on the wing bones, it seems like it got flipped somehow. Maybe the bone axis was not imported/exported correctly for blender?

It would also be helpful if you could share your Blender project file. Instructions for sharing.

Thanks Jakemoyo, file loaded into original post.
I have tried fiddling with weight painting but I'm not experienced enough to know what's happening.
